# awk extract lines that matches specific range of numbers from multiple text files

Tags: awk

For instance,
I have the following in a tab separated text file with two columns:

```
blah    ABC_DE_23154_e53G_12
blah    DEF_GH_23165_f35H_36
blah    CED_BF_56412_c56T_21
```

I am using the following awk script to extract the lines that matches the third number in the second column falling in a specific range (between 23153 and 23167) after the second underscore (which doesn't work):

```
awk -F "_" '$2>23153 && $2<23167' *.txt >> output.txt
```

Output inside the "output.txt" file should be:

```
blah    ABC_DE_23154_e53G_12
blah    DEF_GH_23165_f35H_36
```

I have around 600 text files with around 8000 lines of data in each file.

Thanks,
plasma33

Comment: Can `blah` ever contain a `_`?

Comment: It doesn't, thanks for checking. However, it would be great to have a work around that.

Comment: If you want a solution that includes a workaround for that then you should include that in your sample input/output so we have something to test against that produces a pass/fail result for input that includes that case.

Answer (score 2):

I think the first problem is `$2` in your awk script, because with `$2` is the second column (DE, GH, BF, ...), not the third one where the numbers you want to compare are.

Then, there should be a condition and what you want to do if the condition is met.

`awk -F'_' '($3>23153 && $3<23167){print}' *.txt >> output.txt`

There is a condition in `()` and action in `{}`.

**EDIT:**

As I've been reminded in the comments, `{print}` action is the default one, so you can further simplify the awk script to:

`awk -F'_' '($3>23153 && $3<23167)' *.txt >> output.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Tried with Python

```
k=open('filename','r')
for i in k:
    k=i.strip().split('_')[2]
    if int(k) > 23153<23167:
        print i.strip()
```

output

```
blah    ABC_DE_23154_e53G_12
blah    DEF_GH_23165_f35H_36
blah    CED_BF_56412_c56T_21
```